# Unittest return error that says, "DETAIL: Key (username)=(test123) already exists.'"

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

I am currently trying to test a flash message that I expect to appear when someone attempts to sign up with a username which is already in use. However, I am unsure of how to go about doing this as the method that I am currently using is not working. Here is my testing code:

```
          with app.test_client() as client:
            resp = client.post('/register', data={'firstname': 'test',
                                                  'lastname': 'dummy',
                                                  'username': 'test123',
                                                  'email': 'dummytest@test.com',
                                                  'password': 'password',
                                                  'image': None,
                                                  'state': 'Texas',
                                                  'vax_date': None,
                                                  'covid_status': None},
                                                   follow_redirects=True)
            
            assert b'Username already taken' in resp.data
            
            with self.assertRaises(IntegrityError) as context:
                db.session.commit()
```

And here is the actual endpoint:

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
        try:
            user = User.signup(
                firstname=form.firstname.data,
                lastname=form.lastname.data,
                username=form.username.data,
                email=form.email.data,
                password=form.password.data,
                image=form.image.data,
                state=form.state.data,
                vax_date=form.vax_date.data,
                covid_status=form.covid_status.data)
            db.session.commit()
        except IntegrityError:
            flash("Username already taken", 'danger')
            return render_template('users/register.html', form=form)
        do_login(user)
        return redirect('/user')
    else:
        return render_template('users/register.html', form=form)
```

The error that I get is **DETAIL:  Key (username)=(test123) already exists.** **TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'**

Answer (score 0):

try doing:

```
          with app.test_client() as client:
        resp = client.post('/register', data={'firstname': 'test',
                                              'lastname': 'dummy',
                                              'username': 'test123',
                                              'email': 'dummytest@test.com',
                                              'password': 'password',
                                              'image': None,
                                              'state': 'Texas',
                                              'vax_date': None,
                                              'covid_status': None},
                                               follow_redirects=True)
        
        assert b'Username already taken' in resp.data
        
        with self.assertRaises(IntegrityError) as context:
            db.session.commit()
```

(notice the b prefix to make the string a [byte literal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals))

Comment: thanks. However, now I am getting this error, "DETAIL:  Key (username)=(test123) already exists."